# Google Apps Script to replace text from Google Doc with unique values from spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I have a Google Doc where the same template page is duplicated hundreds of times. The only value I need to change on each page is NAME. I've seen tutorials where Apps Script is used to create individual Docs based on spreadsheet values, but I'd like to replace NAME in a single doc based on the numerical positioning of spreadsheet values as they correlate to page numbers.

For example, NAME on the first page of the doc would be replaced with the value in A1 of the spreadsheet. NAME on the second page of the doc would be replaced with the value in A2 of the spreadsheet.

Any help in creating this script would be much appreciated!

Thank you,
Matt

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote a [script](https://github.com/haohoangofficial/GoogleDocumentReplaceBody/blob/main/doc.js) help you clone multiple google document files and replace body text from google spreadsheet.